# dynamic html in js with angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

At the first I want you will understand what I want to do, maybe the solution that I want to use is not so good I will be happy to hear advices.
 I build a system (website) and the user can fill inputs and I want to send the data in the end of the prosses (form maybe?).
the input is create dynamically with javascript (i mean document.createElement..).

all the inputs is not in a form , just input in the html without form..

now I checked and I saw that when I write in the input its not change the value of the input (maybe its because there is no form?)

Anyways, I thought to use angularJS and use hidden divs thats will get the value of the inputs from the user.. 
 I try to use the angularJS like that:

```
function getDefaultAmount(lines_number){
    var defaultAmount = document.createElement("div");
    defaultAmount.id = "AmountValue_" + lines_number;
    defaultAmount.setAttribute("class", "inlineBlock amountValueStyle");
    defaultAmount.setAttribute("data-ng-app", "myApp");

    var amountInput = document.createElement("input");
    amountInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    amountInput.setAttribute("class", "inlineBlock");
    amountInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "enter amount");
    amountInput.setAttribute("data-ng-model", "name");
    defaultAmount.appendChild(amountInput);

    var amountVal = document.createElement("div");
    amountVal.id = "AmountVal_" + lines_number;
    amountVal.setAttribute("class", "inlineBlock");
    amountVal.setAttribute("data-ng-bind", "name");
    defaultAmount.appendChild(amountVal);

    return defaultAmount.outerHTML;
}
```

and the function that call to getDefaultAmount is:

```
var amount = document.createElement("div");
    amount.id = "Amount_" + lines_number;
    var addClass = document.createAttribute("class");
    addClass.value = "amountStyle";                          
    amount.setAttributeNode(addClass);
    amount.innerHTML = '<span class="inlineBlock">' +"amount:"+ '</span>' + getDefaultAmount(lines_number);
```

this is doesnt work...i mean when I write in the input I didnt see what I write in the other div..

when I put the simple code in the main page and not by the javascript its work fine, I mean that code work fine:

```
<div ng-app="">
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<p ng-bind="name"></p>
```

maybe I don't realy need to use angularJS, the data should deliver with ajax call that I will build..(already built, the problem that I get empty value in the inputs..).

Comment: You can't put html in dom that has angular directives and expect them to work without using `$compile` to let angular compile them

Comment: @charlietfl It might be possible using `angular.bootstrap` after appending content.. but he must have `angular.module` to bootstrap it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $compile to compile the html added.

In your case, after added the html generated below:

```
var amount = document.createElement("div");
amount.id = "Amount_" + lines_number;
var addClass = document.createAttribute("class");
addClass.value = "amountStyle";                          
amount.setAttributeNode(addClass);
amount.innerHTML = '<span class="inlineBlock">' +"amount:"+ '</span>' + getDefaultAmount(lines_number);
```

You need to run

```
$compile(amount)($scope);
```

in your controller.

Comment: well i add the compile line that you wrote affter the amount.innerHTML... line and now i got error: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: $compile is not defined
i tryed to read about it in google its somthing with directives ? 
whats that mean?! =\

Comment: @Rafael You need to inject it to your controller. Have a look of this link https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di